# Opendaylight Clustering Load-Balancing

Tags: opendaylight

I wanted to know if there is possible way to have load-balancing with the Opendaylight Controller when it comes to OpenFlow Switch Ownership.
I know that there is the so called Entity Ownership Service.
The ONOS SDN Controller has a function called *balance-masters* and a extra feature which does this automatically called *Mastership-Loadbalancer*.

Is there a way to send a rpc or a feature I have to activate to get this done? 
I was wondering because the only thing I found was the creation of the **org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.entity.owner.selection.strategies.cfg** file, which didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm told this is not supported by openflowplugin and any loadbalancing would
have to be handled externally.